# C++ CRTP class hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    // ...
};
struct derived : base<derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

Now if I want `derived_from_derived`, I can write:

```
// The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)
template <typename T>
struct base
{
    // ...
};
template <typename T>
struct derived : base<T>
{
    // ...
};
struct derived_from_derived : derived <derived_from_derived>
{
    // ...
};
```

Now suppose I just want a `derived` object.  This doesn't work:

```
derived<derived> obj;
```

Does `derived` have to be abstract, or is there a way to instantiate it?

Comment: Wikipedia attribution rules require a link, I believe. Please link to the article you quote.

Comment: @Mat: short quote = fair use :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own answer is this:

```
struct base
{
    template <typename T>
    struct type
    {
        // ...
    };
};
struct derived
{
    template <typename T=derived>
    struct type : base::type<T>
    {
        // ...
    };
}
struct derived_from_derived 
{
    template <typename T=derived_from_derived >
    struct type : derived::type<T>
    {
        // ...
    };
};
```

Now I can have a `derived::type<> obj`.  Also, parametized inheritance works (e.g. decorator pattern):

```
template <typename whatever>
struct derived_from_whatever 
{
    template <typename T=derived_from_whatever>
    struct type : whatever::type<T>
    {
        // ...
    };
};

derived_from_whatever<derived_from_derived>::type<> obj_whatever;
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for deeper inheritance hierarchies with CRTP usually is implemented by "inserting" CRTP classes between your own classes in the inheritance hierarchy:

```
struct empty
{};

template <class Derived, class Base = empty>
struct crtp_services : Base
{};

class base : public crtp_services<base>
{};

class derived : public crtp_services<derived, base>
{};

class derived_of_derived : public crtp_services<derived_of_derived, derived>
{};
```

Comment: There is a problem here.  How can a function in `base` get a pointer to the concrete class `derived` or `derived_of_derived`?

Comment: @paperjam: could you please add an example of what you need to your question? right now I can only say that you'd have to factor out code which works with specific derived classes to crtp_services, that's what it is needed for.

Comment: Support I have function `base::go() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->go2(); }`.  If I call `derived_of_derived::go()` I will arrive at `derived::go2()` and not `derived_of_derived::go2()`.  Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @paperjam: then you need to move 'go' to the crtp_serivces class: 'crtp_services::go() { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->go2(); }', derived_of_derived::go will be inherited from crtp_services for derived_of_derived and will result in derived_of_derived::go2.

Comment: I don't think that works.  You have multiple crtp_services in your UML inheritance graph and base only sees the one above it.

Comment: @paperjam: ok, time to write some code, I guess, take a look here http://ideone.com/N1Ems. If you need derived::go2 to be called via 'base*' you make your 'go' virtual in the crtp_services, otherwise make it non-virtual.

Comment: I don't want to use virtual functions here.  I want static polymorphism which will allow functions to be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @paperjam: so do you want a method called via pointer to base to result in derived class method called? This not possible without virtual functions or something alike. if you need derived::go to result in derived::go2 to be called then my solution can do it already. Did you take at the example? It shows all possible approaches, there is just nothing else you can do in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's not legal to do that, since the inner derived is not a class, but is itself a template, and not a legal argument for the derived template.

The way that this is usually done is to have a set of derived templates implementations, and then each implementation has a separate class which is used to instantiate that implementation as a concrete class.

```
template <typename T>
struct base
{

};


template <typename T>
struct derived_impl : base<T>
{


};


struct derived : derived_impl<derived>
{


};


template <typename T>
struct derived_of_derived_impl: derived_impl<T>
{


};

struct derived_of_derived : derived_of_derived_impl<derived_of_derived>
{

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
derived<derived> obj;
```

is not allowed because `derived` is a `template` class and the inner `derived` is not yet complete. It needs to have a type like `derived<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "just" a derived object, just like you cannot have "just" `std::vector`, nor can you have `float x = sqrt();`. The type requires an argument, and you must provide it.