# Builder pattern with c++ templates with inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

We have implemented request builders/mutators for our library using generics/template classes. We have common builder functions defined in the template class called CreateBuilder, an example definition of function is

```cpp
template<class TBuilder>
class CreateBuilder {
  TBuilder& setNonce(const string& nonce) {
    nonce_ = nonce;
    logger_.setNonce(nonce);
    return static_cast<TBuilder&>(*this);
  }
  TBuilder& build() {
    return static_cast<TBuilder&>(*this);
  }
}
```

We want to create a hierarchy of builder implementing this base builder.

```
class ABuilder : public CreateBuilder<ABuilder>  {
 ABuilder& setSomething(const string& something) {
   return *this;
 }
}
```

ABuilder().setNonce("a").setSomething("b").build() for sure works well. If we create another level

```
class BBuilder : public ABuilder  {
  BBuilder& setAnother(const string& another) {
    return *this;
  }
}
```

With instance of BBuilder I cannot do this chaining anymore, BBuilder().setNonce("a").setAnother("b") because base builder does static_cast to ABuilder.
Whats the pattern to solve this? One way I could think of is create hierarchy of template classes and template specialized classes will always be the leaf class?

Comment: From `ABuilder`, it looks like `CreateBuilder` makes use of CRTP, but your `CreateBuilder` class does not look like it (unless `TBuilder` is the CRTP parameter, but we can't tell for sure). You should provide us with a proper MCVE.

Comment: I can't follow your code example. "extends" is not c++. Your CreateBuilder returns a TBuilder by casting but is not derived from TBuilder which is not possible. So I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873989/c-crtp-class-hierarchy

Comment: @parktomatomi thanks for fixing the syntax. Looks like I need to create a hierarchy of template classes and implementation will just be the leaf classes.